# Would an outdated Django Server be PCI compliant?

Tags: django, pci-compliance

I have a Django web application that is using version 1.3.1. However, the newest version of Django 1.8.5.

I am just wondering if this would be PCI compliant? From a security perspective, this certainly not a good practice to use web application that is so behind. I tried looking on the web, but there is nothing too explicit about this topic.

Comment: what is "PCI compliant"?

Comment: It is basically a standard to ensure a company and its products process, store and transmit credit card information in a secure environment.

https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/#1

Comment: https://speakerdeck.com/kencochrane/building-pci-compliant-django-applications

Comment: Yeah, I read this. The only possible requirement that is related to it is:

"Requirement 6 - Develop and maintain secure system and application."

This seems so vague to me. Do I need to update my Django version to be secure?

Comment: Absolutely. Django 1.3 is unsupported and insecure, and has known vulnerabilities, including XSS attacks, header spoofing, header injection and a bug that can reveal the CSRF token. These issues have been fixed in all supported versions of Django -- currently 1.7.x and 1.8.x (LTS).

Comment: Thanks @knbk. Appreciate the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCI compliance has a requirement - "Develop and maintain secure system and application."

From @knbk comment:

"Django 1.3 is unsupported and insecure, and has known vulnerabilities, including XSS attacks, header spoofing, header injection and a bug that can reveal the CSRF token. These issues have been fixed in all supported versions of Django."

There is a very  good chance that it will not be PCI compliant because it is not secure.